# Write from AutoHotkey to (Build) Output panel in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, autohotkey

How to configure Sublime Text 3 and/or Autohotkey (2.0 or 1.1) to output strings from `1` to `2`? I'm trying to write some strings therein for script debugging purposes.

I've found AHK functions `OutputDebug "text"` and `FileAppend "text",*` (star stands for standard output), but the text isn't redirected to the panel - is there perhaps a plugin or Build System configuration to accomplish this?

[image: Problem]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to program a key sequence to write something to the Build pane? If so, it is not possible with AHK, you'll need to write a plugin for Sublime overriding/extending the standard build execution program `exec.py`.

Comment: I'm trying to output some debugging information therein, just like you guessed. I'll made it clearer in my question - thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the Sublime-AHK doesn't support that, or they've built their stdout differently. Have you tried it with Scite4AutoHotkey? I use it all the time in that editor.

Comment: SciTE4AutoHotkey works, yes, although I would prefer not to have one editor for each scripting language - I would like to have it all in Sublime if possible. Hence the question, maybe somebody already had success in that? I don't know where to start - don't even know if that Build Output Panel is stdout at all.

Comment: How/What Syntax Highlighter did/do you use?

Comment: Unfortunately this was 4.5 years ago and I do not use Sublime Text anymore (switched to Visual Studio Code, which is the same + more, but other hotkeys). I'll still try to guess that I installed the syntax highlighting from within Sublime Text via "Install Package" (or whatever it's called) and searched for ones with "AutoHotkey" or "AHK" in name. There probably were several of them - I just tried them all one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out `FileAppend text,*` (or `FileAppend % "text",*`) is the answer after all. I tried it before asking this question, alas it didn't work then, because:

1. I used Unicode chars inside `text`. This prevented the function from writing the string at all. When I changed `text` to contain only ASCII chars, it was displayed without problems.
2. The file was saved with `UTF-8 (with BOM)` encoding. When I changed encoding to `UTF-8`, `text` was printed even if it contained Unicode characters.